# What is the "40 minute rule" about?

Tags: discussion

I tried to post a question on the site, and received a message to the effect, "you can't post anything else until 40 minutes are up."

In fact, I hadn't posted anything for three days. (I have two posts on the site.) But prior to posting, I had conducted some "searches" which may have been mistaken by the system for posts.

I haven't encountered this on other SE sites. Is this feature peculiar to Open Data or is it a function of my low rep on the site? What is the rationale, anyway?

And why might the system mistake my searches for posts?

Comment: Did you post on another site? or Are you on a shared IP at school or work?

Comment: @bluefeet: No to the shared IP. How would my posting on another site affect my posting on this site? I've never had the 40-minute rule invoked on me on other sites (I'm on about 80), maybe 20 "active."

Comment: See this post on MSO http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265/426671 the posting rate limit is network wide.

Comment: @bluefeet: Ok.1)  This is a new policy. 2)The system knows that I'm a new user here, and doesn't know that I'm not a new user on say, History SE, so it restrains me here for a post on History. Because I don't have a posting rate limit on my "established" sites.

Comment: that is correct. If no one else fleshes out a full answer I will when I'm back in front of a computer.

Answer (score 5):

A few months ago, we implemented [a change to how often new users can post throughout the network](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265/426671). This was done for a variety of reasons, including preventing spammers from inundating multiple sites at a time.  As the answer explains:

> The new-user ask limit is now one question every 40 minutes, network-wide. That means only 1 question every 40 minutes on Stack Overflow, but also means you'd need to wait 40 minutes after asking a question on, say, Woodworking to ask a related question on Crafting or Home Improvement.

You were blocked because you ran into the 40 minute network limit when you attempted to post.